# Pipeline Dependency Graph

Tags: airflow, apache-falcon

I am looking to create a dependency graph for a few pipelines in my cluster. I am trying to show the start and end point of my data and all the flows of data in between the two points. I am looking to use either apache airflow or apache falcon to accomplish this task. Please let me know if you have any suggestions on what tool to use and how to get started with this project. Please also link any documentation related to apache falcon. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Airflow has a nice UI which allows you to view your DAGs as a tree, graph, or even Gantt chart. [Check this out](https://airflow.apache.org/ui.html#graph-view) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. Can airflow be used for monitoring without using its scheduler? I already have an HDFS where jobs are already scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own UI views in Airflow, allowing you to display whatever you're looking for. See Airflow [plugins](https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html) documentation. Have a look also at the Airflow plugins [github](https://github.com/airflow-plugins/Getting-Started) for examples

Comment: Thank you. Can airflow be used for monitoring without using its scheduler? I already have an HDFS where jobs are already scheduled.

Comment: If you already scheduled your jobs in another Workflow Management System, can't you monitor data flow in there?

Comment: The HDFS uses YARN which takes care of scheduling jobs. I was looking at Airflow to see if I can change the scheduler configuration to the existing one.